# Add product to PrestaShop 1.5 via Web Service

Tags: php, web-services, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I try to add a product via web service and I receive bellow error code:

```
RETURN HTTP BODY
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<errors>
<error>
<message><![CDATA[Internal error. To see this error please display the PHP errors.]]></message>
</error>
</errors>
</prestashop>
```

I am searching 2 days but nothing. Please can anyone help me?
My Code is below.

```
define('DEBUG', true);
define('_PS_DEBUG_SQL_', true);
define('PS_SHOP_PATH', 'http://mywebsiteinlocalhost.gr/dev...shop/trunk/src/');
define('PS_WS_AUTH_KEY', 'CBYB5G5UVRA7FCN7JK2WZ625DFWG8SK3');
require_once ('./PSWebServiceLibrary.php');
$webService = new PrestaShopWebservice(PS_SHOP_PATH, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY, DEBUG);
$opt = array('resource' => 'products');
$xml = $webService->get(array('url' => PS_SHOP_PATH.'/api/products?schema=synopsis'));
$resources = $xml->children()->children();

unset($resources->position_in_category);
unset($resources->manufacturer_name);

$resources->price = '1000';
$resources->active = '1';
$resources->quantity = '50';
$resources->link_rewrite = 'blabla';
$resources->name->language[0][0] = 'blabla';
$resources->description->language[0][0] = '<p>blabla</p>';
$resources->description_short->language[0][0] = 'blabla';
$resources->associations = '';

$opt = array('resource' => 'products');
$opt['postXml'] = $xml->asXML();
$xml = $webService->add($opt);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resource Product is kind of very important for Prestashop.
I have checked quickly the schema 'synopsis' (.../api/products/?schema=synopsis). There are 12 fields marked as required true!
In you example, the default parent category is missing for example!
That is one of the reason why it didn't work!

Answer (score 2):

In PrestaShop 1.5
Open `defines.inc.php` from config folder

find

```
define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false);
```

change **false** -> **true** it will start showing exact error.

This error is occurring due to

```
$resources->quantity = '50';
```

You can not modify quantity from xml. Just comment this line. I hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

check the weather you have given the correct PS_SHOP_PATH and PS_WS_AUTH_KEY.

and also check for the permission from your prestashop backend.

Comment: it is correct I checked again and again. Finaly I create my own product insert method

Answer (score 0):

To see real webservice error message please activate PHP error display in config/config.inc.php

@ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
define('_PS_DEBUG_SQL_', true);