# I am getting ![CDATA[ Internal error. To see this error please display the PHP errors. error in Prestashop

Tags: web-services, prestashop-1.5

I am new to Prestashop. Please help me. I was trying to use webservices but I am receiving this error. What should I do? I am using Prestashop 1.5.

Comment: Include all details, like errors and what you have tried. Then we will able to help you.

Comment: I am getting ![CDATA[ Internal error. To see this error please display the PHP errors - This is the error I am facing while I try to use api in the address bar. Say for example www.example.com/api.

Comment: Internal error, may be you missing some configuration.

Comment: Thank you solved!..:)..Yea..you were correct. Thanks a ton..:) I forgot to check yes under "WebServices".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internal error, may be you missing some configuration. Check all the configuration before running web application.

Comment: Sure! Thank you. :)..Have one more doubt- I have a Restful service where I could retrieve customer details. How can I update? Please find the reference link :- http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Chapter+5+-+Modification+-+Update+client

Comment: I think I need more details. Why don't you post another question and mention each detail at there. Include detail like restful service output what do you want to update and what you have tried till now.

Comment: Sure :).. I will post as another question

Comment: Please check the question posted here :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29891971/how-to-update-clients-record-using-webservice-in-prestashop

Comment: @MaheshMohan make this answer correct so other will find answer. I am check it out.

Comment: It's baffling to me that this is an acceptable answer. What types of things could be misconfigured? How does one go about displaying the php errors?

Answer (score 4):

You need to set `_PS_MODE_DEV_` to `true`. This file is found at `config/defines.inc.php`.

Once this flag is enabled, you will see a useful error message instead of the generic one.

See [Add product to PrestaShop 1.5 via Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19929719/add-product-to-prestashop-1-5-via-web-service) for where I found this tip.

Answer (score 1):

Check all the configuration before running web application. Make sure Webservice is enabled in the back office.:)